# Creating a DataRow from a search in a DataTable/DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am making progress on this database access stuff... 
Here's what I need to do:
I have an existing DataSet(and therefore a DataTable) that is defined in the class namespace, and I am trying to make a function that allows the user to pick from a list of items, and use the `SelectedItem.Value`(which contains a unique Primary Key from the Database) to show more information about the item that is selected. I believe I need to search through the DataSet and read it into something like a DataRow so that I can display the values from that(there is a way to do this based on column name, correct?)

I just can't figure out how to say "copy/select the row whose primary key "partnumber" is equal to `SelectedItem.Value`"

Comment: Have you looked at 'DataTable.Select()': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h71xaeh0.aspx

Comment: I have
`DataRow[] myRows = queryTable.Select("productsid='" + selectionList.SelectedItem.Value + "'");`

but it returns an error saying could not find column [prodcutsid] even though that is clearly one of the column names(unless it is case sensitive in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three common methods

1. Use [DataRowCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk.aspx) can only be used if a column has been defined as a primary key

   ```
   var row = table.Rows.Find(SelectedItem.Value)
   ```
2. Use [DataTable.Select(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) which uses a filter like a string

   ```
   var rows = table.Select("IdFieldSelectedItem.Value = " + SelectedItem.Value);
   var row = rows[0];
   ```
3. Use [Linq to Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415.aspx)

   ```
   var row =  (from t in table.AsEnumerable()
               where t.Field<int>("Id") == SelectedItem.Value
               select t).First();
   ```

Comment: @Conrad Frix Ok, so I was using the Select method properly. However, it seems like my DataSet contains no data. Any ideas why? I have `public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page { DataSet queryData = new DataSet(); DataTable queryTable = new DataTable();` Then in a button event handler, I query the database(actually a web service) like: 
`protected void updateTable(oject sender, EventArgs e) 
{
queryData = pws.Query...//web service method
queryTable = queryData.Tables["parts"] }` 
Then this function 
`protected void updateData(object sender, EventArgs e) { // as shown in your answer }`

Comment: When are you calling `.Select()` is that also from the button handler that filled the dataset?

Comment: No, the .Select() is called from the "selectedIndexChanged" handler for a drop down list.
I am displaying a table, then want the user to select from a dropdown list after the table is up. Upon selecting an item from the drop down, I want additional information to appear.

Comment: Ok so every time you have a post back the `queryData` and `queryTable` get reinitialized. In order to keep the DataSet alive you're going to need to do something. Typically people use `Session` for that. e.g Add `Session["QueryTable"] = queryTable;` to your button handler and `if(IsPostBack) { queryTable = (DataTable)Session["QueryTable"]; }` to your page load. See [Persist c# objects across postbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309185/persist-c-sharp-objects-across-postbacks)

Comment: Excellent! That solved my problem. I think I'm finally starting to understand all this data and binding stuff! :-)